# PLCC adapter -exists?

Tags: integrated-circuit, adapter

I have a PCB assembly containing amongst other things a socketed 52-pin PLCC.  I want to remove the PLCC IC and insert an adapter that allows me to clip-lead into the socket so I can access the circuitry on the PCB.

Basically I want something like the device pictured below, but the opposite gender on the PLCC end.  IOW, the PLCC end of the adapter plugs into a socket rather than clipping over an IC.  Is there such a thing? I’ve not been able to find it.

(Per the rules I haven't asked for a particular source - only if it exists - **Is there such a thing?** - however my question's been marked closed)

[image]

Comment: Once upon a long time ago I had a Microchip PicMaster emulator with a 'pod' for the PIC17C756, which terminated in a PLCC plug-in adapter just like you describe - so I can confirm that such a thing does (or at least did) exist. Whether it was a custom MIcrochip assembly or something they purchased as a standard component I couldn't say.

Comment: I'm aware of such adapters as part of expensive in-circuit emulators "back in the day", but have had ZERO luck finding anything similar today.

Comment: Could you get away with making your own out of a pcb with castellated edges?

Comment: @Bryan. Perhaps, but I don’t have a way of designing or manufacturing such a board.

Comment: 52-pin PLCC *plug* seems to be what you need to search.  [Winslow W9383 52 Pin Small Footprint PLCC Plug](https://warwickts.com/4411/W9383-52-Way-SMT-PLCC-Plug)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a quick search for "PLCC plug" and got tons of viable hits. Image search shows exactly what you're looking for to help narrow results

[image: PLCC plug]

https://www.ironwoodelectronics.com/products/plcc-clips-socket-plugs/

https://www.adapt-plus.com/shop?category=PLCC-plugs

https://www.winslowadaptics.com/app/uploads/2019/03/PLCC-Plug-Range-Datasheet.pdf

If those are expensive or long lead time then you might be able to DIY yourself a castellated board using

- PCB design software (I use Diptrace, and enjoy it),
- a PCB fab house (I use Oshpark and enjoy that too - the stickers are a nice touch)
- and some snipping or sanding through vias: https://hackaday.com/2021/12/11/snip-your-way-to-diy-pcb-castellations/

[image]